# Proof that lagrange and newton's interpolation are the same

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Its known that newton's interpolation and lagrange interpolation gives the same value 
All i need is to prove it

Comment: That's because there exist a unique  interpolating polynomial, no matter what method you use to compute it.

Comment: @Crostul yeah i already know that all im asking about is proof that if i use lagrange or newton i'll get the same value

Comment: Let $N$ be the polynomial you get with Newton, and $L$ the polynomial you get with Lagrange. They are interpolating polynomials, hence they are equal.

Answer (score 5):

There is a unique polynomial of degree $\leq$ (number of points - 1) going through the points.  Lagrange and Newton both produce such a thing, therefore the same thing.