# What are the pros and cons of Newton's Interpolation formula?

Tags: interpolation

What are the pros and cons of Newton's Interpolation formula for unequal intervals against Lagrange's interpolation formula?

Comment: [Proof that lagrange and newton's interpolation are the same](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682126/proof-that-lagrange-and-newtons-interpolation-are-the-same)?

Comment: Depends. If you're using the barycentric form of the Lagrange formula, it and the divided-differences form have comparable efficiency.